# Updating table using group by sum

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.  One is a detail table that contains quantity info and has the following structure

```
> mysql> DESCRIBE summary_finished;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| db_id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| finished_id   | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |
| finished_name | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |
| qoh           | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |
| value         | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+


    mysql> DESCRIBE detail_finished;
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
    | Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default |
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
    | db_id       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
    | finished_id | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |
    | quantity    | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |
    | value       | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
```

In detail_finished there are many items that have the same finished_id.  What I am trying to accomplish is combining items that have the same finished_id and update that sum to the summary_finished.qoh field.  This is what I have so far:

```
function set_qty($total, $finished_id){
    global $connection;
    $query="UPDATE summary_finished 
    SET qoh={$total} 
    WHERE finished_id='$finished_id'";
    $quantity=mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($quantity);
    }


$query="SELECT finished_id, SUM(quantity) FROM detail_finished GROUP BY finished_id";
$result=mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  set_qty($row['SUM(quantity)'], $row['finished_id']);
   }
```

I know the sums are calculating correctly as I can echo them straight out, however I cannot get my table to update.  Forgive me for the sloppy code I am very new with mysql entirely.  Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you use text type to store id. By the way

```
 update summary_finished as sf
 inner join (
 select finished_id, 
        sum(quantity) as total
 from detail_finished 
 group by finished_id )as t
 set sf.qoh = t.total
 where sf.finished_id = t.finished_id
```

Comment: This is giving me incorrect numbers.  About 3,000 off.  I have text type id's as this is the id that is used in our main inventory system.  Example ID is M70951BLA.  Could this be where my issue is?  Your query turned up the exact number that my way overcomplicated script was before I started trying to use sum.

Comment: If your codes are like M70951BLA you can use varchar type. Text is not necessary. What do you mean by incorrect numbers? Can you make some example? I tried my query and results are right.

Comment: if i dump both the finished_detail and the finished_summary both the totals of quantity and qoh should match up.  But they don't.  Will change type to varchar and rerun

Comment: Are we sure that we have to match finished_id and not finished_name from the other table?

Comment: Yah it is finished id.  Both the fields use that same id style number.  The finished_name is actually a description of the item.  After changing to varchar results still the same.

Comment: Let me undestand. Some finished_id have the right total and other not?

Comment: Make some debug. Check a specific finished_id that gives you a wrong result and run the query on it.  select finished_id, sum(quantity) as total from detail_finished where finished_id = 'blablabla'. Then check if finished_id has some carriage return or line feed at the end of the field. This is what I suppose. Wait for other advices. Regards.

Comment: I may be thinking about this too hard.  If I can get correct values by using SUM on the detail_finished table then would it be easier to just pull over a description from summary_finished.finished_name, and get everything into one table, perhaps a third table.  `$query="SELECT finished_id, SUM(quantity) FROM detail_finished GROUP BY finished_id";
$result=mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['finished_id']." - ".$row['SUM(quantity)'];
echo "<br />";
$i+=$row['SUM(quantity)'];
}
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo $i;`